# The order of link-related pseudo-classes

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I try to understand what is the most correct order of link-related pseudo-classes.

The order below seems to be *almost* correct, that is *almost* perfect, because you can have a different color for each state and each state is visually different from any other.

```css
a:link    { color: blue; }
a:visited { color: violet; }
a:hover   { color: orange; }
a:focus   { color: green; }
/* note that :active must be the last, notwithstanding
that after you click the link, the last state you will
observe visually is :focus */
a:active  { color: red; }
```

```html
<a href="#">cick me!</a>
<a href="#">cick me!</a>
```

However, this order is not *really* perfect.

Press the Tab key to select one of the two links in the example. You will see its color is green and there is an outline around it (in Chrome and Edge, the outline is black; in Firefox, the outline is the same color as the text, that is, it will be green). There are no problems yet.

Now hover such a keyboard-focused hyperlink with mouse cursor or press the Enter key to "click" it with keyboard. The color will stay the same, that is, it will stay green.

Of course, this doesn't look "fair". Mouse users can have different color for each state, that is, five colors, while keyboard users have only three colors, that is, `:hover` and `:active` states doesn't visually differentiate from `:focus` for them.

How to solve this problem? That is, how to make each click-related state visually different for both mouse and keyboard users?

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with my own. And my own question is clear and accurate. I will be grateful if it will be reopened.

Comment: I don't know about "clear and accurate", for example you talk about `:hover` in combination with keyboard navigation, where it does not apply in the first place. And bringing an arbitrary criterion such as "fair" into it, makes very little sense to me. But either way, maybe combining multiple pseudo classes in a selector gets you to whatever thing you think you need to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to combine them, with no success yet.

Comment: I am simply not clear on what you actually want to achieve here. _"while keyboard users have only three colors, that is, :hover and :active states doesn't visually differentiate from :focus for them"_ - there _is_ no `:hover` when you are using the keyboard. And `:active`, by definition, applies only for that short moment the element is _getting_ activated - when using a mouse, that would only be as long as the button is actually pressed down. I don't know if there even is any equivalent to that specified for activation via keyboard.

Comment: _There is no `:hover` when you are using the keyboard_ - True, but what I mean is hovering it with the mouse. That is, the user selects a hyperlink with the keyboard and **then** (for some reason), he or she hovers that hyperlink with the mouse. I do understand such a workflow is somewhat unusual and silly, of course. _I don't know if there even is any equivalent to that specified for activation via keyboard._ - Good point, thanks.

Comment: _"the user selects a hyperlink with keyboard and then (for some reason), he or she hovers it with a mouse"_ - then you have a link that is in the `:focus` state _and_ the `:hover` state at this point, so by combining both pseudo classes, you can format it differently now if desired: `a:focus:hover { color:black; }`